# How to resize an object in photoshop after adding pantone color to a part of that object?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So I made a selection of the petals, created an alfa channel and added a pantone color to them.

When I try to resize the whole thing, like in the picture, the selection stays in place. And I can't select that channel with cmyk channels together.

Is there a way I can resize the whole object after adding a color?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- Load the Alpha Channel and create a **Fill Layer** with the Pantone content
- Resize the object and the Fill Layer all together.

[image]

[Photo](https://unsplash.com/photos/5GKdpmo0wI8) from unsplash.com

---

**Or**

- Transform the object layer
- Click the Alpha Channel and Select All
- **Menu Edit** > **Transform** > **Again**

[image]

Comment: Basically the same answer as mine, but you need to convert the fill layer to a spot channel when the composition is done.

Comment: Yes, replacing the channel.

Comment: The last edit is a good trick!

Comment: I've got the idea after your comment

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think it's impossible.

Channels and layers kind of live in separate worlds. Working with spot colors is more manual work than CMYK/RGB.

You can't even have spot colors within a *Smart Object*, which could have been nice.

### Some ideas for workarounds

- Keep the petals and the background in separate files and create the final composition in InDesign/Illustrator.
- Use the selection from the spot channel to create a temporary ordinary layer. When the whole composition is done, create the final spot channel and delete/turn off the ordinary layer.